# sales_order_shipment_track_save_after get order ID

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, sales-order, fatal-error

I want to integrate sms trigger on `sales_order_shipment_track_save_after` event. I have created a custom module and the trigger is being called but I am not able to get orderid from shipment. Following is the code from my observer.

```
$shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();
```

but I keep on getting

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\company\app\code\local\Company\Smstrigger\Model\Observer.php on line 11

can someone please point me to correct code for the same.

Magento version 1.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one. Shipment object is in `track` key.

```
  $event = $observer->getEvent();
  $track = $event->getTrack();
  $shipment = $track->getShipment();
  $order = $shipment->getOrder();
```